# Is there some way to cleanup a Python Package?

Tags: python, package, resource-cleanup

Python Packages have explicit means to initialize when imported (the "mandatory" `__init__.py` script); is there some way to obtain the reverse (i.e.: define a script to be run whenever Package is unloaded, either explicitly or because interpreter terminates)?

My current use would be:

I have a simple server which receives commands through a named pipe, so first thing `__init__.py` does is to create such a pipe (along with other initializations). I would like to "automagically" delete the file when Package is teared down, for whatever reason (as far as possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ateexit module

https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html

register your cleanup function in the __init__ file